# Form validation datatype error in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I get **Login Done** in all the cases and also this treats the value as the string instead of the number ....

---

```
function valid() {

  let value = document.getElementById('box').value;

  alert(typeof value)
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 1 || value > 20) {
    alert("Login Done")
  } else if (name = '') {
    alert("try agin")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Negate the `isNaN(value)` check. Also convert it to a number before the comparison to reduce the confusion

```js
function valid() {

  let value = document.getElementById('box').value;
  
  let parsedValue = isNaN(value) ? 1 : parseInt(value, 10);
  
  console.log(typeof value);
  console.log(typeof parsedValue);
  
  if (parsedValue < 1 || parsedValue > 20) {
    console.log("Login Done")
  } else {
    console.log("try agin")
  }
}

valid();

document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('keyup', valid);
```

```html
<input id="box" value="21" />
```